# Streaming a blob from Azure storage - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-storage, filestream, memorystream

I am using asp.net webforms.

I have pdfs in Azure storage that I need to process. I am using PDFJet library in order to do that.

I would like to 
stream the pdf without downloading it as I have to process a large number of pdfs.

I am using the following function to stream the pdfs from Azure:

```
public MemoryStream DownloadToMemoryStream(DTO.BlobUpload b)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Conn.SNString(b.OrgID);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(b.Container);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(b.FileName);
    var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),//assuming the blob can be downloaded in 10 miinutes
    }, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
    {
        ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=file-name"
    });
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blob.DownloadToStream(ms);
        return ms;
    }

}
```

And in the aspx.cs page the following code to read the pdf stream:

```
BufferedStream pdfScript = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(ScriptPath + Script, FileMode.Open));

SortedDictionary<Int32, PDFobj> objects = pdfFinalScript.Read(pdfScript);
```

However I get the error message:  Cannot access a closed Stream

If I download the pdf to disk, this is the function I use, this work but it is not practical:

```
blockBlob.DownloadToFile(b.LocalPath + b.FileName, FileMode.Create);

BufferedStream pdfScript = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(ScriptPath + Script, FileMode.Open));
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Cannot access a closed Stream

According to error information, it indicates that you need to reset stream position.

<del>Please have a try to reset the stream position before return it.
blob.DownloadToStream(ms);
ms.Position = 0;  //add this code
return ms;</del>

**Updated:**

`ms` was closed if out of using section. So please have a try to use the following code.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  blob.DownloadToStream(ms);
  ms.Position = 0
  ms.CopyTo(stream);
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I added ms.Position=0 but I have the same issue. This is the message I get if I ckeck the value of pdfScript.Position:'pdfScript.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232798
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Cannot access a closed Stream."
    ObjectName: ""
    Source: "mscorlib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()\r\n   at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Position()"
    TargetSite: {Void StreamIsClosed()}

Comment: @Anne ms was closed if out of using section. I have updated answer.

Comment: Hi Tom, it is working now, however before copying ms to stream you have to set the position to ms to 0: ms.Position=0 then ms.CopyTo(stream). Thank you

Comment: Yes. you are right.Sorry for missing that. I updated the answer.